# Undefined method 'click' - Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, rspec, automated-tests, cucumber, selenium-chromedriver

I'm learning test automation. I'm using the 'cucumber', 'rspec', 'selenium-web driver' framework in Ruby language. In the tests, I was able to perform almost every step. An error occurred when automating the click of a button.

```
Step definitions:
    Quando(/^clicar o botão "([^"]*)"$/) do |botaoSave|
 # @navegador.find_elements(:xpath, "//*[@id='SAVE']").trigger("click")
  @navegador.find_elements(:xpath, "//*[@id='SAVE']").click
end
```

Error Message Displayed:

```
 E clicar o botão "SAVE"                                  # features/step_definitions/criarConta.rb:92
      undefined method `click' for #<Array:0x00000002847680> (NoMethodError)
      ./features/step_definitions/criarConta.rb:94:in `/^clicar o botão "([^"]*)"$/'
      features/criarConta.feature:30:in `E clicar o botão "SAVE"'
    Então a conta será cadastrada corretamente               # features/criarConta.feature:31

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/criarConta.feature:7 # Cenário: Cadastrando uma conta

1 scenario (1 failed)
23 steps (1 failed, 1 undefined, 21 passed)
```

Answer (score 1):

`find_elements` returns an array. You need to use `find_element`, which returns one element

```
@navegador.find_element(:xpath, "//*[@id='SAVE']").click
```

Comment: When I changed to: @navegador.find_element(:xpath, "//*[@id='SAVE']").click                                                                       
 unknown error: Element <input title="Save" accesskey="a" class="button primary" onclick="var _form = document.getElementById('EditView'); _form.action.value='Save'; if(check_form('EditView'))SUGAR.ajaxUI.submitForm(_form);return false;" type="submit" name="button" value="Save" id="SAVE"> is not clickable at point (287, 20). Other element would receive the click: <a href="#" id="grouptab_1" class="dropdown-toggle grouptab" data-toggle="dropdown">

Comment: @DavidsonJacob It looks like the actual button is covering the element you are trying to click. Try `@navegador.find_element(:xpath, "//*[@title='Save']").click`

Comment: I changed the code but another error is being displayed 
                                                               
 @navegador.find_element(:xpath, "//*[@title='Save']").click          
 unknown error: Element <input title="Save" accesskey="a" class="button primary" onclick="var _form = document.getElementById('EditView'); _form.action.value='Save'; if(check_form('EditView'))SUGAR.ajaxUI.submitForm(_form);return false;" type="submit" name="button" value="Save" id="SAVE"> is not clickable at point (287, 20).